# Unable to zoom image on double tap

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im loading an imageview as follows.  self.displayReceivedImageScrollView is a  scrollview property defined in header file.

```
   _displayImage.image = nil;


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
            NSData *data0 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:savedValue]];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data0];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                _displayImage.image = image;
            });
        });


    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

    [self.displayReceivedImageScrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

Following is my handler for doubleTap. I want the image to be zoomed when the user double taps the image.

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if(self.displayReceivedImageScrollView.zoomScale > self.displayReceivedImageScrollView.minimumZoomScale)
        [self.displayReceivedImageScrollView setZoomScale:self.displayReceivedImageScrollView.minimumZoomScale animated:YES];
    else
        [self.displayReceivedImageScrollView setZoomScale:self.displayReceivedImageScrollView.maximumZoomScale animated:YES];

}
```

But the problem is that, the image is not being zoomed. handleDoubleTap method is not at all getting fired why is that so?

Comment: If I were you, to zoom in/out of a component, I would use the CGAffineTransformScale method (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/). It's really easy to use, and you should try it with a pinch gesture recognizer. If you want to, I can also post a sample of a pinch gesture recognizer which is actually used to zoom in/out ;)

Comment: Please give me a sample code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can make zoom enable by put your view in ScrollView, and config :

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat minimumZoomScale;     // default is 1.0
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat maximumZoomScale;     // default is 1.0. must be > minimum zoom scale to enable zooming
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the recogniser to an image view.

Have you enable user interaction?

```
self.displayReceivedImageScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

By default the interaction will be disabled and so it will not respond to any touch events.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable user interaction simply select your ImageView from interface builder and go to Attributes inspector and check the box for interaction.

[image]

Comment: You're also able to do it programmatically by using the `serUserInterractionEnabled:` method, with a sample it give us: `[the_Object_You_Want setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]`or put it to YES if you want to, it depends.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the sample code you asked me in the comment:

Here is how to declare the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`

```
-(IBAction)scaleImage:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

And in your `ViewDidLoad` or somewhere else add it to your `View` or something else:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *scaleImage =[[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scaleImage:)];
[View_Or_Somehting_Else addGestureRecognizer:scaleImage];
```

Note: the code of the Recognizer and the place you're adding it to your view must be in the same file, or pass it as an argument in a method ;)